# What is the best way of removing the outer tag and inner tag using jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to remove the outer two div tags and two span tag from the below piece of html.

```
<div class="c44 c44v0">
       <div class="c44w">
          <blockquote>
             <span class="c44-lquote">
                <!-- # -->
             </span>
             <em>Being able to seamlessly integrate</em> with those providers via real-time data feeds.
             <span class="c44-rquote">
                <!-- # -->
             </span>
          </blockquote>
          <div class="c44credit">Luke Kelly,<br /> Vice President of Finance, Carbon</div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

After removing it should look like

```
 <blockquote>
             <em>Being able to seamlessly integrate</em> with those providers via real-time data feeds.
          </blockquote>
          <div class="c44credit">Luke Kelly,<br /> Vice President of Finance, Carbon</div>
```

I tried to do it with the below piece of code

```
doc.select("div.c44 c44v0 > div.c44w").forEach(div -> {
                div.parent().replaceWith(new Element(Tag.valueOf("div"), "").attr("align", "center").html(div.html()));
            });
```

But with this code i'm able to remove the two div tag but i'm replacing with another div tag. Is there any better way to remove the two div tag completely along with the span tag.... Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job.

First remove span tags:

```
    doc.select("span.c44-rquote").remove();
```

Then select elements you want to keep:

```
    Elements childs = doc.select("div.c44w > *");
```

Remove divs with childrens:

```
    doc.select("div.c44.c44v0").remove();
```

And append again elements you want to keep in the place where original divs were:

```
    for(Element e : childs) {
        doc.select("body").first().appendChild(e);
    }
```